# “union all” two data set with different column names in sas using Hadoop connection

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sas, union-all

I am trying to append two datasets in a proc sql query. I am using Hadoop connection for this job. One data has one extra column which I am using to subset the data. Code patch:

```
proc sql;
Create table t1 as select * from connection to Hadoop
(select temp.* from
(select a.* , “ ” as var1 from table1(keep= &keeplist) a 
union all 
select b.*  from table2(keep= &keeplist var1) b where b.var1 = “XX”) temp); 
quit;
```

This code gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Prepare error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException 
line 1:67 mismatched input ‘(‘ expecting ) near ‘table1’ in sub query source
```

Previously I have also tried excluding the sub query and that resulted in error saying : `missing EOF at ‘(‘ near ‘table1’`.

Any know solution to this sort of query? otherwise I am thinking to pull separately and then append, that might incur higher cost.

Comment: You're using explicit pass through, that means the SQL in the the PROC SQL needs to be Hadoop compliant, not SAS compliant. You're using SAS concepts in the SQL statements (e.g `KEEP`) which are not valid in Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In that case how shall I filter the data in SQL statement. My Keeplist in the sas keep statement is atleast 200 var long. What would be the common practice in Hadoop

Comment: As each individual select uses only one table, there should be no need to quality the fields with `a.` or `b.`  and you can write `(select &keeplist , “ ” as var1 from table1 union ...`

Comment: Recreate your macro variable to be separated with commas and include them in the SELECT list instead of using an * to select everything.

Comment: You might also want to consider trying `fedsql` instead of doing explicit passthrough with sql. It's designed to handle these types of problems natively.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of your comments. The code worked fine after removing the KEEP statement and selecting the variables in SQL query itself